# T SQL Count Component Sets based on Component Quantities

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 4 Components that make up a set. The quantities for the set are C1 = 1, C2 = 1, C3 = 1, and C4 = 2. I'm looking for the total number of sets by Stores_Code and how many extra I have remaining of each component. Below is the query to obtain the current counts.

```
select STORES_CODE 
    , case when LTFLS.PART_ID = '300432' then sum(ON_HAND_QTY) else 0 end as [C1]
    , case when LTFLS.PART_ID = '300433' then sum(ON_HAND_QTY) else 0 end as [C2]
    , case when LTFLS.PART_ID = '300107' then sum(ON_HAND_QTY) else 0 end as [C3]
    , case when LTFLS.PART_ID = '300108' then sum(ON_HAND_QTY) else 0 end as [C4]

from LTFLS 

where PART_ID in('300432','300433','300107','300108')
    and ON_HAND_QTY <> 0
group by STORES_CODE , PART_ID
order by STORES_CODE
```

Any assistance is appreciated. I'm still a beginner at SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
select STORES_CODE 
    , sum(case when PART_ID = '300432' then ON_HAND_QTY else 0 end) as [C1]
    , sum(case when PART_ID = '300433' then ON_HAND_QTY else 0 end) as [C2]
    , sum(case when PART_ID = '300107' then ON_HAND_QTY else 0 end) as [C3]
    , sum(case when PART_ID = '300108' then ON_HAND_QTY else 0 end) as [C4]

from LTFLS 
where PART_ID in('300432','300433','300107','300108')
    and ON_HAND_QTY <> 0
group by STORES_CODE
order by STORES_CODE
```

### OR

```
select STORES_CODE 
    , PART_ID
    , sum(case when PART_ID = '300432' then ON_HAND_QTY else 0 end) as [C1]
    , sum(case when PART_ID = '300433' then ON_HAND_QTY else 0 end) as [C2]
    , sum(case when PART_ID = '300107' then ON_HAND_QTY else 0 end) as [C3]
    , sum(case when PART_ID = '300108' then ON_HAND_QTY else 0 end) as [C4]

from LTFLS 
where PART_ID in('300432','300433','300107','300108')
    and ON_HAND_QTY <> 0
group by STORES_CODE , PART_ID
order by STORES_CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
    Select TB.STORES_CODE 
          ,Sum([C1]) As [C1]
          ,Sum([C2]) As [C2]
          ,Sum([C3]) As [C3]
          ,Sum([C4]) As  [C4]

    from (

            Select STORES_CODE 
                  ,PART_ID
                , case when LTFLS.PART_ID = '300432' then ON_HAND_QTY else 0 end as [C1]
                , case when LTFLS.PART_ID = '300433' then ON_HAND_QTY else 0 end as [C2]
                , case when LTFLS.PART_ID = '300107' then ON_HAND_QTY else 0 end as [C3]
                , case when LTFLS.PART_ID = '300108' then ON_HAND_QTY else 0 end as [C4]

            from LTFLS 
            where PART_ID in('300432','300433','300107','300108')
                and ON_HAND_QTY <> 0

        ) TB
    Group by TB.STORES_CODE
```